# add value in each row of a file at a certain position

Tags: shell

Here is a csv file in the linux system. This is one line from the file.

:/var/opt/data# vi data_2018_07.csv

`LGPAR,DATA,61543261,98747321900,gprs,464623201315531,NRI,1.45890,0.000000,0.0000,,2016-01-12 01:50:58,2016-01-12 15:50:58,0,11,0,0,0,0,25250,NO,NO,NO,1056.gz`

Similarly, we have 300000 line in that file. All we want is to add incremental values (24th value) at a place between NO,xxxx.gz in each row iteration.

`LGPAR,DATA,61543261,98747321900,gprs,464623201315531,NRI,1.45890,0.000000,0.0000,,2016-01-12 01:50:58,2016-01-12 15:50:58,0,11,0,0,0,0,25250,NO,NO,NO,1, 1056.gz`
`LGRDR,DATA,61543261,98747321900,gprs,464623201315531,NRI,1.45890,0.000000,0.0000,,2016-01-12 01:50:58,2016-01-12 15:50:58,0,11,0,0,0,0,25250,NO,NO,NO,2, 1057.gz`

Can we do that in complete file for all rows using a small shells script? Note: rows are different in each row.

Answer (score 1):

a quick way with awk:

```
awk -F'[.,]' '{x=1+$(NF-1);sub(/[0-9]+\.gz/,x".gz")}7' file
```

Test with some data:

```
kent$  cat f
foo,bar,foo,bar,123.gz
foo,bar,foo,bar,1057.gz

kent$  awk -F'[.,]' '{x=1+$(NF-1);sub(/[0-9]+\.gz/,x".gz")}7' f
foo,bar,foo,bar,124.gz
foo,bar,foo,bar,1058.gz
```